# Как при толстом клиенте, не дать возможности использовать менеджер баз данных?

Tags: база-данных, безопасность, firebird

Есть сервер СУБД (Firebird но можно привести пример и с любым другим),
на нем находится БД.

Созданы пользователи и им розданы права на объекты БД.

Есть толстый клиент в котором находится вся бизнес логика.

Пользователи знают свой логин, пароль и адрес сервера СУБД.

Как пользователю не дать возможности использовать менеджер баз данных
для прямого доступа к БД?

Comment: Какой в этом смысл?

Comment: Не дать очень умному и хитрому пользователю, через менеджер баз данных залезать в БД и править ее в ручную

Comment: Так эта проблема решается просто. Если залез и испортил, то уволить (или расстрелять...). Остальным острастка будет. Главное тут -- неотвратимость наказания

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаете триггер на `ON CONNECT`.

В нем анализируете название исполнимого файла:

```
SELECT MON$REMOTE_PROCESS
FROM MON$ATTACHMENTS
WHERE N$ATTACHMENT_ID = CURRENT_CONNECTION
```

Если не нравится - вызываете исключение, и соединение обрывается.

Comment: Заодно можно логировать такие попытки и уведомлять руководство, для принятия административных мер.

Comment: Обходится переименованием exe файла менеджера? :)

Comment: Да. А также галочкой "Preserv database/transaction triggers from firing" в IBExpert или параметром `-nodbtriggers` у `isql`. Но это максимально близкое из возможного к тому, что хотел автор вопроса.

Comment: "PashaPash" да я подумал о том же, но если я могу создать триггер на коннект, то смогу добавить еще какую то логику поведения для клиента (первое что пришло в голову это алерты) и если поведения не будет то соединение оборву.

Answer (score 0):

Пусть ваш толстый клиент как-то преобразует полученные от пользователя логин и пароль, прежде чем передать их на сервер.